# How to leverage browser caching for static HTML assets?

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, browser-cache, nginx-config

I have built my static html on heroku. Here's the link: https://askheating.herokuapp.com/

Now when I am performing a test on GTMetrix, I have got a very bad score due to leverage browser caching.

This is my .htaccess script

```
 AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot 
 AddType application/x-font-ttf .ttf
 AddType application/x-font-opentype .otf
 AddType application/x-font-woff .woff
 AddType image/svg+xml .svg

# BEGIN Expire headers
<ifModule mod_expires.c>


ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 5 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 604800 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 600 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/xhtml+xml "access plus 600 seconds"
</ifModule>
# END Expire headers

# BEGIN Cache-Control Headers
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
  <filesMatch "\.(ico|jpe?g|png|gif|swf)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "public"
  </filesMatch>
  <filesMatch "\.(css)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "public"
  </filesMatch>
  <filesMatch "\.(js)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "private"
  </filesMatch>
  <filesMatch "\.(x?html?|php)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "private, must-revalidate"
  </filesMatch>
</ifModule>
# END Cache-Control Headers

# This is for gzip, which compresses files
<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
  mod_gzip_on Yes
  mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
  mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
  mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
  mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
  mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
  mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
  mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>


#Remove the Need for www in Your URL

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.askheating.herokuapp.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://askheating.herokuapp.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

# disable directory browsing

Options All -Indexes
```

But still I'm getting this

[image]

Now I dont know how to play with nginx, and whwre to find all that stuff..
please help!!

Answer (score 3):

**Browser caching for .htaccess**

The code below tells browsers what to cache and how long to "remember" it. It should be added to the top of your .htaccess file.

```
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

*Save the .htaccess file and then refresh your webpage.*

**How to set different caching times for different file types**

You can see in the above code that there are time periods like "1 year" or "1 month". These are associated with file types, as an example the above code states that a .jpg file (image) should be cached for a year.

If you want to change that and say you want your jpg images cached for a month you would simply replace "1 year" with "1 month". The values above are pretty optimized for most webpages and blogs.

**Alternate caching method for .htaccess**

The above method is called "Expires" and it works for most people using .htaccess so it takes care of caching for most people who are just getting started.

After you are more comfortable with caching, you may want to try Cache-Control, another method of caching which gives us more options.

It is also possible the expires method did not work for your server, in that case you may want to try to use Cache-Control.

**Cache-Control**

Cache-Control allows us to have a bit more control of our browser caching and many people find it easier to use once setup.

Example use in `.htaccess` file:

```
# 1 Month for most static assets
<filesMatch ".(css|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|ico)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
</filesMatch>
```

The above code is setting a cache control header depending on file type.

---

https://varvy.com/pagespeed/leverage-browser-caching.html

https://medium.com/@codebyamir/a-web-developers-guide-to-browser-caching-cc41f3b73e7c